# MacOSX partition failure

Tags: macos, partitioning, kali-linux, boot-partition

It started when I was installing Kali Linux on my MacBook with a dual boot, I used a Live USB to install and when going through the install process, I shrunk my macOS partition on the hard drive to make space for the Linux install, the shrinking was taking rather long and it was still going as I went to sleep.

I woke up in the morning and the the shrinking had finished fine so I continued the install. It finished installing so I rebooted and it went straight to GRUB 2.

I tried booting into Kali but I was greeted with a hard drive error. I repeatedly rebooted but it would not boot every time. I gave up and I tried to boot into macOS when I was greeted with a circle with a slash in it.

Then, I booted into recovery mode and had a look on Disk Utility.
I am shown two things:

1. a Linux swap
2. a Kali partition

but no Macintosh HD.

I then went into terminal and ran `diskutil list` and I was greeted with this

[image]

I assume that my OS and data is stored in `disk0s2` `Apple_CoreStorage` and if it is not then I am screwed (No Backup).

Any help recovering my OS and data would be highly appreciated as I have some important stuff in there. I will edit any info you need on to the thread.
Many Thanks, Evan

Answer (score 0):

Solved by simply removing the drive from the MacBook and inserting it into another pc running a live USB of Debian. Copying over files now  close shave.